# How do we convert exponent format into actual number from PHP

Tags: php

How do we convert `8.64E+14` into actual value from PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Cast to a float if not already a float, and `printf()` the result:

```
printf('%.0f', (float) '8.64E+14');
```

Note that casting to int won't work because that cast does not understand numbers expressed as strings in scientific notation. And on some systems, your given number is too large to fit into an int so PHP may make it a float instead.

Comment: That prints: -1391067136 on some architectures.

Comment: @Tim: Prints 864000000000000 for me, it's due to integer overflow on some builds. Printing as a float dropping the decimals should work.

Comment: Can your build handle 8.64E+24?

Comment: @Tim: Nope... rounding fall-off.

Answer (score 1):

It's already an actual value. The value type is float.

```
$float = 8.64E+14;
var_dump($float); //will give you float 8.64E+14
```

Comment: actaually its a csv file value but i want to integer value

Comment: Well, you could cast it using `(int)`, you might lose precision though. See the manual : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting

Comment: `(int)` does not recognize scientific notation.

Comment: @BoltClock, yeah I guess. You could use something like `$int = (int) sprintf('%.0f', $float);` but then you'd be hitting the boundary of int